# How to calculate Integral error from MCMC

Tags: autocorrelation, markov-chain-montecarlo, error, numerical-integration

I've recently started using Markov Chain Monte Carlo to calculate integrals, but I can't seem to find how to calculate the error for such an integral. In the standard case of importance sampling, the integral is defined as,

$$ I = \int f(x) dx \approx \mathbb{E}\left[f(x)\right]_{x \sim p(x)} = \frac{1}{N}\sum_{i=1}^{N} \frac{f(x)}{p(x)} \iff x \sim p(x) $$

and, its associated error is defined by,

$$\frac{N}{N-1}\left( \mathbb{E}\left[f(x)^{2}\right]_{x \sim p(x)} - \mathbb{E\left[f(x)\right]_{x \sim p(x)}^{2}} \right)$$

However, these definitions are only valid because the sampling of $x \sim p(x)$ is independent and identically distributed; however, by definition of a Markov chain samples are dependent on the previous sample, and hence this doesn't apply.

How exactly can an error be calculated if samples are dependent? I've tried searching for an answer but yet to find one. I did see one solution which involved the autocorrelation time of the chain, although I can't find it anymore.

Thank you in advance!